# Internal server error while creating invoice

Tags: admin, invoice, magento-1.4

I am getting a blank page while submitting invoice and when I am checking this in firebug to find some issue it is saying internal server error.
But when I am clicking back button on browser, it is taking me to the order invoice page and showing two messages. 
`Invoice has been created.`
`The order does not allow creating an invoice.`
It is creating invoice but showing blank page and two contradicting messages.
I have checked Magento and server logs but didn't find anything related to it. 
Please let me know if somebody faced this issue earlier and how it has been fixed or any related stuff that I can check.

Comment: Did you enabled the error showing and then checked?

Comment: Yes, but it is not showing anything.

Comment: Can you check the template file and make sure you have closed all the html tags?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and there are open html tags and also there are no php short tags.

Comment: Can you put log statements inside each if condition in Mage_Sales_Model_Order model's canInvoice() function and check the order status?

Comment: I have a hunch that something is calling `invoce->save()` twice. The first time it creates the invoice, the second one cannot because you already have invoiced the full amount. I would check the third party extensions.

Comment: Thanks, Marius for your comment. For me this issue is fixed, in my case the problem was related to db, someone has attached dev site db with live and when I reverted back to original db, issue was gone.